# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) - Error only occurs when code is nested

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on a project that retrieves data about car auctions, I have it set up to request a custom Ebay URL that uses their api, I request the page and convert it to a JSON for handling. The code runs with no errors at all if the code is by itself but if I put it within a function or within a conditional statement or anything else that means it is nested it will give me the JSON error 
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
My code is here, however I dont know if it is an issue with my code as it works fine when it is not within a function

```
ebayurl = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?\
SECURITY-APPNAME=KyleOsbo-CarSearc-PRD-adf6708f9-c75353fe\
&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced\
&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0\
&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB\
&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON\
&REST-PAYLOAD\
&categoryId(0)=9801\
&outputSelector(0)=SellerInfo\
&keywords="+"honda%20civic" #The custom url was created based on my needs, I only want to search ebay uk and only within the cars category

apiResult = requests.get(ebayurl) #Request the custom url
parsedresult = apiResult.json() #Convert url to json format in order to extract information easier
for item in (parsedresult["findItemsAdvancedResponse"][0]["searchResult"][0]["item"]): #JSON is set up as multi dimensional array, looks within it to extract values
    title = item["title"][0]
    price = item["sellingStatus"][0]["convertedCurrentPrice"][0]["__value__"]
    itemURL = item["viewItemURL"][0]
    location = item["location"][0]
    itemid = item["itemId"][0]
    with sqlite3.connect("results.db") as db: #Connecting to table ready to insert new records
        cursor = db.cursor()
        values = (itemid, title, price, location, itemURL) #Declaring values that will be inserted,preventing sql injection, these values will change upon every iteration
        sql = """ INSERT INTO ebay_results(item_id, title, price, location, itemURL)
                VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
                """
        cursor.execute(sql, values) #Inserts a new record for every item found
        db.commit()
```

The error occurs at
    parsedresult = apiResult.json()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ikoze\Documents\Computer Science\Coursework 
files\carrySearch.py", line 94, in <module>
    parsedresult = apiResult.json() #Convert url to json format in order to 
extract information easier
  File "C:\Users\ikoze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
```

packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
        return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\ikoze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
    32\lib\json__init__.py", line 354, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Users\ikoze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
    32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Users\ikoze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
    32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: You probably indented your multi-line string, making the URL invalid.

Comment: @Aran-Fey this was it! Thank you so much, something as simple as that and was driving me crazy I completely skipped past it. Appreciate that :)